# Why so many pointers?

Tags: delphi

Searching for references of Win32 LDAP API functions, I found the following [JwaWinLDAP.pas](https://github.com/magicmonty/delphi-code-coverage/blob/master/3rdParty/JWAPI/jwapi2.2a/Win32API/JwaWinLDAP.pas) unit.

On this unit, to function [ldap_search_st](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366975(v=vs.85).aspx) is declared:

```
function ldap_search_st(ld: PLDAP; base: PAnsiChar; scope: ULONG;
  filter, attrs: PAnsiChar; attrsonly:  ULONG; var timeout: TLDAPTimeVal;
  var res: PLDAPMessage): ULONG; cdecl;
```

The timeout: **TLDAPTimeVal** parameter is declared as:

```
  PLDAPTimeVal = ^TLDAPTimeVal;
  l_timeval = packed record
    tv_sec: Longint;
    tv_usec: Longint;
  end;
  LDAP_TIMEVAL = l_timeval;
  PLDAP_TIMEVAL = ^LDAP_TIMEVAL;
  TLDAPTimeVal = l_timeval;
```

On the code, if I use something like:

```
procedure foo;
var
  TimeVal: PLDAPTimeVal;
begin
 ldap_search_st(foo1, Nil, 0, PAnsiChar('(objectClass=*)'), Nil, 0, TimeVal, foo2);
end;
```

Compiler gives me error:

> [dcc32 Error] Types of actual and formal var parameters must be
>   identical

because of the timeout parameter. If I change TimeVal type to **TLDAPTimeVal** it compiles and the application works.

The question is: 
when I see declaration of types in Delphi, they are always like:

```
type
 PType1 = ^Type1
 Type1 = record...
```

In the specific example cited, it could be:

```
  l_timeval = packed record
    tv_sec: Longint;
    tv_usec: Longint;
  end;
  TLDAPTimeVal = l_timeval;
```

and it would work the exact same way (I think)... Why so much confusion on this kind of declaration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
type
 PType1 = ^Type1
 Type1 = record...
```

Above type declaration declares two types - one is record, and another one is typed pointer for that specific record type. They are usually declared in pairs, because they are related. But if your or any code does not need typed pointer, it does not need to declare pointer type.

---

Function `ldap_search_st` uses only declared record type. But some other functions in that unit expect pointer as parameter. That is why declaration has both.

Code in question is LDAP Windows API header translation for Delphi. Windows API uses pointers for passing structures to functions.

API translations are usually complex and sometimes have seemingly superfluous declarations. For completeness, translations usually contain all original declarations (symbols) - those are `l_timeval`, `LDAP_TIMEVAL` and `PLDAP_TIMEVAL`, and while those would be sufficient to use the API, there are two additional declarations whose only purpose is providing Delphi style names for more user friendly experience `PLDAPTimeVal` and `TLDAPTimeVal`

If you take a look at original LDAP function declarations they all use pointers for passing structures. For instance:

```
ULONG ldap_search_st(
  _In_  LDAP             *ld,
  _In_  PCHAR            base,
  _In_  ULONG            scope,
  _In_  PCHAR            filter,
  _In_  PCHAR            attrs[],
  _In_  ULONG            attrsonly,
  _In_  struct l_timeval *timeout,
  _Out_ LDAPMessage      **res
);
```

and

```
ULONG ldap_connect(
  _In_ LDAP         *ld,
  _In_ LDAP_TIMEVAL *timeout
);
```

There is one difference in those two considering `timeout` parameter.

`ldap_search_st` expects non-null value in `timeout` parameter - and Delphi translation of that parameter is `var timeout: TLDAPTimeVal` to match that intent more clearly - that declaration prevents you from accidentally passing null. While `TLDAPTimeVal` is not a pointer type, having `var` keyword makes our `timeout` parameter to behave like one. Behind the scenes Delphi will pass pointer to the structure and that will perfectly match original function declaration.

On the other hand in `ldap_connect` `timeout` can contain null value. In that case default timeout value will be used. The only way to satisfy that requirement is to use pointer type to timeout structure. In another words `PLDAPTimeVal` and Delphi translation of that function declaration is

```
function ldap_connect(ld: PLDAP; timeout: PLDAPTimeval): ULONG;
```

Comment: I understood why on this declaration it's so confuse, because other functions requires that "confusion"... The part of the typed pointer, I really still not understand when use a pointer, etc... But this is another question, I should read more about it on the docs... Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: That code is interfacing with Windows API (those function parameters are defined by the API) where pointers are used for passing structures. So you cannot avoid pointers.

Comment: Please read: [Addressing pointers](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html). Windows APIs are C-compatible, so they tend to use pointers in abundance. Sometimes, such pointers are translated into `var` parameters in Delphi interface units. So the Delphi declaration does not always exactly match the pointers in the original MSDN documentation for such an API function. See the part about *reference parameters* in the above article.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis And as additional read [Pitfalls of converting](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html)

Comment: @Dalija: well, I have read it already. But userXYZ should perhaps do that. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Well, I thought you might want to read it again... yes, it is meant as reading suggestion for OP or anyone else interested in header translations.

Answer (score 0):

It is the matter of coding standards and conventions and there is so many of them because LDAP declarations were adopted into PSDK and then translated to Delphi. Additionally, since Pascal doesn't allow pointer type declaration (eg `^Integer`) within formal parameters unlike plain C (eg `int *`), corresponding pointer types were added to declaration.

Here, I marked various conventions in the declaration, note the difference in casing and prefixes:

```
  PLDAPTimeVal = ^TLDAPTimeVal;   // Delphi pointer (Econos convention)
  l_timeval = packed record       // canonic structure (LDAP convention)
    tv_sec: Longint;
    tv_usec: Longint;
  end;
  LDAP_TIMEVAL = l_timeval;       // Windows structure (PSDK convention)
  PLDAP_TIMEVAL = ^LDAP_TIMEVAL;  // Windows pointer (PSDK convention)
  TLDAPTimeVal = l_timeval;       // Delphi structure (Econos convention)
```

Curious thing: the forward declaration (**before** structure) of Delphi pointer is also mandated by [Econos convention](http://web.archive.org/web/20160910012512/http://www.sourceformat.com/coding-standard-delphi-econos.htm#ObjectPascal_Record). Original PSDK code declares the pointer **after** the structure.